# how to add columns in pandas if its not present in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have following array of column names in python.

```
 col = ['code','ro','quantity','amount']
```

I get the processed dataframe from a function which may or may not have all the above columns. I want to add columns with default value as 0 if they are missing from the array.

e.g. I get following dataframe

```
df1

code      ro      quantity
123       342     34.56
123       445     54.56
```

My desired dataframe would be

```
code      ro      quantity  amount
123       342     34.56     0
123       445     54.56     0
```

How can I do it in pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) over `axis=1`:

```
df.reindex(col,fill_value=0,axis=1)
```

---

```
   code   ro  quantity  amount
0   123  342     34.56       0
1   123  445     54.56       0
```

Comment: can fill_value be a map of defaults to column names?

Answer (score 2):

Code:-

```
col = ['code','ro','quantity','amount']
for i in col:
    if i not in df1.columns:
        df[i] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

1). Short and simple solution if you know the basics of python and you do not have to memorise any new method.

```
col = ['code','ro','quantity','amount']

for var in col:
    if var not in df1.columns:
        df[var] = 0
```

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in col :
   if i not in df:
      df[i] = 0
```